# Java problema n + 1 consulta com Map

Tags: java

Estou com um problema de performance onde tenho 10 carros alugados e preciso popular um gráfico de linhas com esses 10 carros no entanto está demorando muito tempo para abrir a tela.
Segue a lógica que utilizei para fazer
Teria uma maneira de melhorar esse código para a tela abrir mais rápido pois, e complicado para o usuário ter que esperar mais de 4 minutos para a tela abrir.
Ao abrir a tela e feita a consulta 10 vezes (primeiro for de carros) e mais 200 consultas dentro do while 
Qual seria a melhor solução para esse problema?

```
public List<CarroVO> carrosAlugadosPorMes() {

List<CarroVO> listaCarrosAlugados = new ArrayList<>();
List<LinkedHashMap<String, List>> carrosAlugados = mapCarros();

// obterCarrosAlugados = id = marcaCarro 
for (LinkedHashMap carroAlugado : carrosAlugados) {

LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> carroMesTotal = new LinkedHashMap<>();
LocalDate dataAtual = LocalDate.now();
LocalDate ultimoMes = dataAtual.minusMonths(11);
LocalDate mesBalanco = LocalDate.of(ultimoMes.getYear(),
ultimoMes.getMonth(), ultimoMes.getMonth().length(ultimoMes.isLeapYear()));
LocalDate ultimoDiaMes = LocalDate.of(dataAtual.getYear(), dataAtual.getMonth(),
dataAtual.getMonth().length(dataAtual.isLeapYear()));

while ( mesBalanco.isBefore(ultimoDiaMes) ||
mesBalanco.isEqual(ultimoDiaMes)) {

Month mes = mesBalanco.getMonth();
String noMesAtual = mes.getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT, new Locale("pt", "BR"));
int numeroDias = mes.length(mesBalanco.isLeapYear());
Calendar calendar = ultimoDiaMes(mesBalanco.getYear(), mesBalanco.getMonthValue(), numeroDias);
//Aqui faz a consulta para popular o gráfico de linhas onde utilizo nativeQuery contendo duas pesquisas uma para tipo 1 de carro e outra para o tipo 2 de carro 
Integer totalCarros = carroDao.consultaBanco(calendar, new ArrayList( carroAlugado.values() ));

carroMesTotal.put(noMesAtual, totalCarros);

mesBalanco = mesBalanco.plusMonths(1);
}

CarroVO carroVO = new CarroVO();
carroAlugado.forEach((k,v) -> carroVO.setMarcaCarro(k.toString()) );
List<LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>> totalCarros = new ArrayList<>();
totalCarros.add(carroMesTotal);
carroVO.setTotalCarro(totalCarros);
listaCarrosAlugados.add(carroVO);
}

return listaCarrosAlugados;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Existem alguns pontos críticos nesse trecho de código. Eu fiz uma amostra bem simples mas funcional para testar (Se alguém mais quiser analisar, fica mais fácil). Acredito que uma boa refatorada seja o passo mais importante e, acredito também, que se chegou nesse patamar de 4 minutos esse refactor é urgente.

Notei que bem no core do for-while temos a consulta à base e isso é muito preocupante. Qual a performance dessa consulta em base exponencial?

Talvez o trecho abaixo possa ser refatorado e extraído, para uma execução única ou um acesso mais pontual à base. Sendo assim, me parece que será necessário refatorar a estrutura. Para isso é preciso entender bem  o que está por traz do carrosAlugadosPorMes().

```
  Calendar calendar = ultimoDiaMes(mesBalanco.getYear(), mesBalanco.getMonthValue(), numeroDias);
  //Aqui faz a consulta para popular o gráfico de linhas onde utilizo nativeQuery contendo duas pesquisas uma para tipo 1 de carro e outra para o tipo 2 de carro 
  >>>>>>> CRÍTICO <<<<<<
  carroDao.consultaBanco(calendar, new ArrayList( carroAlugado.values() ));
  >>>>>>>>>>>><<<<<<<<<<
  carroMesTotal.put(noMesAtual, totalCarros);
```

**[ EDITADO ]**

Então Rodrigo, fiz alguns ajustes e refatorei alguns pontos que podem te ajudar. Lembrando que estou no escuro em relação a tudo que está envolvido no seu projeto. Estou levando em consideração que você possa criar uma procedure na base de dados.

**Alterações:** Criação de um filtro por Marca. (A criação desse filtro talvez envolva alterar alguma estrutura a mais) Como pode perceber o *while* foi abstraído para o médoto **obterCarrosMesTotalProc(...)** que deve ter sua lógica delegada a uma procedure.

```
    public List<CarroVO> carrosAlugadosPorMesBy(String marca) {

            List<CarroVO> listaCarrosAlugados = new ArrayList<>();
            List<LinkedHashMap<String, List<CarroVO>>> carrosAlugados = mapCarrosPor(marca);

            LocalDate dataAtual = LocalDate.now();
            LocalDate ultimoMes = dataAtual.minusMonths(11);
            LocalDate mesBalanco    = LocalDate.of(ultimoMes.getYear(), ultimoMes.getMonth(), ultimoMes.getMonth().length(ultimoMes.isLeapYear()));
            LocalDate ultimoDiaMes  = LocalDate.of(dataAtual.getYear(), dataAtual.getMonth(), dataAtual.getMonth().length(dataAtual.isLeapYear()));

            for (LinkedHashMap<?, ?> carroAlugado : carrosAlugados) {

                CarroVO carroVO = new CarroVO();
                carroAlugado.forEach((k,v) -> carroVO.setMarcaCarro(k.toString()));

                LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> carroMesTotal = new LinkedHashMap<>();
                List<LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>> totalCarros = new ArrayList<>();

                mesBalanco = obterCarrosMesTotalProc(mesBalanco, ultimoDiaMes, carroAlugado, carroMesTotal, totalCarros);
                carroVO.setTotalCarros(totalCarros);

                listaCarrosAlugados.add(carroVO);
            }

            return listaCarrosAlugados;
        }
```

Outro ponto a ser destacado é o método mapCarro() que agora recebe um filtro passando para **mapCarrosPor(marca)**.

```
 List<LinkedHashMap<String, List<CarroVO>>> carrosAlugados = mapCarrosPor(marca);
```

Acredito que se seguir essa linha a performance deve melhorar sensivelmente. Segue abaixo uma **nova amostra** com as alterações propostas.

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.TextStyle;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Random;

public class AppTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Aluguel aluguel = new Aluguel();

        List<CarroVO> listaVolks = aluguel.carrosAlugadosPorMesBy(Marca.VOLKS);
        List<CarroVO> listaToyota = aluguel.carrosAlugadosPorMesBy(Marca.TOYOTA);

        listaVolks.forEach(val -> System.out.println(val.getMarcaCarro() + ": " + val.totalCarros));
        listaToyota.forEach(val -> System.out.println(val.getMarcaCarro() + ": " + val.totalCarros));
    }
}

class Aluguel {

    //MOCK - Dao mockado para simulação
    CarroDao carroDao = new CarroDao();

    public List<CarroVO> carrosAlugadosPorMesBy(String marca) {

        List<CarroVO> listaCarrosAlugados = new ArrayList<>();
        List<LinkedHashMap<String, List<CarroVO>>> carrosAlugados = mapCarrosPor(marca);

        LocalDate dataAtual = LocalDate.now();
        LocalDate ultimoMes = dataAtual.minusMonths(11);
        LocalDate mesBalanco    = LocalDate.of(ultimoMes.getYear(), ultimoMes.getMonth(), ultimoMes.getMonth().length(ultimoMes.isLeapYear()));
        LocalDate ultimoDiaMes  = LocalDate.of(dataAtual.getYear(), dataAtual.getMonth(), dataAtual.getMonth().length(dataAtual.isLeapYear()));

        for (LinkedHashMap<?, ?> carroAlugado : carrosAlugados) {

            CarroVO carroVO = new CarroVO();
            carroAlugado.forEach((k,v) -> carroVO.setMarcaCarro(k.toString()));

            LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> carroMesTotal = new LinkedHashMap<>();
            List<LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>> totalCarros = new ArrayList<>();

            //Delegado a uma procedure
            mesBalanco = obterCarrosMesTotalProc(mesBalanco, ultimoDiaMes, carroAlugado, carroMesTotal, totalCarros);
            carroVO.setTotalCarros(totalCarros);

            listaCarrosAlugados.add(carroVO);
        }

        return listaCarrosAlugados;
    }

    /*
     * MOCK - ESSE CONTEÚDO DEVE SER DELEGADO A UMA PROCEDURE
     * NA BASE DE DADOS
     */
    private LocalDate obterCarrosMesTotalProc(
            LocalDate mesBalanco, 
            LocalDate ultimoDiaMes,
            LinkedHashMap<?, ?> carroAlugado, 
            LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> carroMesTotal,
            List<LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>> totalCarros) {

        String noMesAtual;
        int numeroDias;

        while (mesBalanco.isBefore(ultimoDiaMes) || mesBalanco.isEqual(ultimoDiaMes)) {

            noMesAtual = mesBalanco.getMonth().getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT, new Locale("pt", "BR"));
            numeroDias = mesBalanco.getMonth().length(mesBalanco.isLeapYear());

            Integer totalCarrosBase = carroDao.consultaBanco(ultimoDiaMes(mesBalanco, numeroDias), new ArrayList<>(carroAlugado.values()));
            carroMesTotal.put(noMesAtual, totalCarrosBase);

            mesBalanco = mesBalanco.plusMonths(1);
        }

        totalCarros.add(carroMesTotal);
        return mesBalanco;
    }

    public List<LinkedHashMap<String, List<CarroVO>>> mapCarrosPor(String filtro){

        //MOCK
        List<LinkedHashMap<String, List<CarroVO>>> returnList = new ArrayList<>();
        LinkedHashMap<String, List<CarroVO>> lhm = new LinkedHashMap<>(); 
        List<CarroVO> listaCarros = new ArrayList<>();

        if(Marca.TOYOTA.equals(filtro)) {

            CarroVO carroVO = new CarroVO("Hatch",2018);
            listaCarros.add(carroVO);

            carroVO = new CarroVO("Sedan",2019);
            listaCarros.add(carroVO);

            lhm.put("Tyota", listaCarros);
        }

        if(Marca.VOLKS.equals(filtro)) {

            CarroVO carroVO = new CarroVO("Hatch",2018);
            listaCarros.add(carroVO);

            carroVO = new CarroVO("Sedan",2019);
            listaCarros.add(carroVO);

            lhm.put("Volks", listaCarros);
        }

        returnList.add(lhm);

        return returnList;
    }


    //MOCK
    public Calendar ultimoDiaMes(LocalDate mesBalanco, int numeroDias){
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, mesBalanco.getMonthValue());
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, mesBalanco.getYear());
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, numeroDias);
        cal.set(Calendar.DATE, cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DATE));
        return cal;
    } 

}

class Marca {
    public static String VOLKS = "VolksWagen";
    public static String TOYOTA = "Toyota";
}

class CarroVO {
    private String modelo;
    private String marcaCarro;
    private Integer ano;
    List<LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>> totalCarros;

    public CarroVO() {}
    public CarroVO(String modelo, Integer ano) {
        super();
        this.modelo = modelo;
        this.ano = ano;
    }
    public String getModelo() {
        return modelo;
    }
    public void setModelo(String modelo) {
        this.modelo = modelo;
    }
    public Integer getAno() {
        return ano;
    }
    public void setAno(Integer ano) {
        this.ano = ano;
    }
    public List<LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>> getTotalCarros() {
        return totalCarros;
    }
    public void setTotalCarros(List<LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>> totalCarros) {
        this.totalCarros = totalCarros;
    }
    public String getMarcaCarro() {
        return marcaCarro;
    }
    public void setMarcaCarro(String marcaCarro) {
        this.marcaCarro = marcaCarro;
    }
}

//MOCK 
class CarroDao {
    public Integer consultaBanco(Calendar calendar, Collection<Object> carrosAlugados){
        Random r = new Random();
        return r.nextInt((500 - 1) + 1) + 1;
    }
}
```

Retorno obtido após executar o código acima:

```
Volks: [{jun=500, jul=362, ago=324, set=97, out=202, nov=290, dez=479, jan=310, fev=98, mar=129, abr=294, mai=295}]
Tyota: [{jun=215, jul=90, ago=395, set=15, out=384, nov=458, dez=124, jan=20, fev=324, mar=374, abr=204, mai=184}]
```

Comment: E como ficaria para melhorar a perfomace desse código?

Comment: Sem saber o que está envolvido é difícil, mas penso que alguns passos poderiam ser dados:
1. Avaliar a query _consultaBanco(calendar, new ArrayList( carroAlugado.values() ));_ Qual a performance dessa query? Alguma parte da lógica poderia ser delegada para uma procedure?

2. Antecipar alguma parte da informação desacoplando o código do while. Talvez para isso, seja necessário criar consultas mais pontuais.

3. De alguma forma as informações de data poderiam se tornar um objeto? Como estão os testes de integração, apresentam o mesmo problema de performance?

Comment: Não poderia adicionar em um VO o resultado das 4 queries?

Comment: Editei o código acima e pontuei dois seguimentos. Utilização de filtros e a abstração do while para uma procedure. Confere aí, por favor e me diz se deu certo. Uma outra linha a ser seguida seria o uso de threads.

Comment: Como ficaria a procedure no método 
    private LocalDate obterCarrosMesTotalProc(
            LocalDate mesBalanco, 
            LocalDate ultimoDiaMes,
            LinkedHashMap<?, ?> carroAlugado, 
            LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> carroMesTotal,
            List<LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>> totalCarros) 
Sou iniciante em banco de dados e gostaria de uma ajuda